# Telescope update got rid of both the settings and submit post ability. How do i get rid of update and remove the please update from the top?

Tags: meteor, telescope

The settings panel in admin and the ability of submit post has disappeared only the submit is staying. I have not changed in my code anything that would make this change. It also seems to have occurred in the Telescope meta. Also how do I get rid of the update please banner.

Answer (score 1):

It's an Autoform bug from the Meteor 1.0.4 update.  Fix hopefully coming soon.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/790/